# Rust print option custom struct

Tags: rust

In rust, I want in my `impl fmt::Display for MainStruct`, to be able to print another struct.

```
#[derive(Clone, Default)]
pub struct MainStruct {
    pub child: Option<ChildStruct>
}
#[derive(Clone, Default)]
pub struct ChildStruct {
    pub field: String
}

impl std::fmt::Display for MainStruct {
   fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
       write!(f, "MainStruct: child:{}", self.child)
   }
}
impl std::fmt::Display for ChildStruct {
   fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
       write!(f, "ChildStruct: field:{}", self.field)
   }
}
```

I have tried with the default `{}` formatter, and with the `{:?}` formatter, but without any success.

Comment: Can  you illustrate what you want to display respectively when `child` is `Some(_)` and `None`?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to implement `Debug` rather than `Display`. `Display` isn't implemented for `Option<T>` no matter what `T` implements, and that's on purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that `Option<T>` has not implemented the `Display` trait. So you have to get the value out of the option. The easiest to do so is `.unwrap()`. This however panics if the option is None. (other methods for unpacking are `expect`, `match`, …)

If you use `.unwrap()` the value is moved out of the Option. So the Option would now be invalid as it would not contain anything anymore. The compiler prevents this with an error `cannot move out of 'self.child'`.

So what you actually want is a reference that does not consume the child. So you want `&T` or `&mut T` from the Option. You can do that by using the `.as_ref()` to convert `Option<T>` to `Option<&T>`. Then if you do `.unwrap()` on that the compiler wont complain anymore as you just copy a `&T` pointer.

so your code compiles if you change the following:

```rust
impl std::fmt::Display for MainStruct {
   fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
       write!(f, "MainStruct: child:{}", self.child.as_ref().unwrap())
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that `unwrap` panics if `self.child` is `None`.

Comment: Any solution to prevent that? Checking `if self.child.is_some()` or `if !self.child.is_none()` ?

Comment: you are right. I adjusted the solution I hope things are ok now.

Answer (score 3):

Since `Option` does not implement `Display`, you have to write some logic yourself to handle two possible cases. The simplest way might be to just match on the `Option` explicitly:

```
impl std::fmt::Display for MainStruct {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "MainStruct: child: ")?;
        match self.child.as_ref() {
            Some(child) => write!(f, "Some({})", child),
            None => write!(f, "None"),
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a2889d5788177b9897e47fbd07476383) with a short test case.